# execution time of a query in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I have just started evaluating Neo4j how possible alternative to postgres for a data warehouse built specifically for the integration and analysis of complex biological data.
I have imported some tables into Neo4j and started benchmarking the execution time of some relevant queries.
I was wondering what is the best way to measure them. I'm using neo4j-shell tool, but I'm not sure this is the best approach....maybe implementing a tiny client using Java API or the Traversal framework is better?
And how measure the "real" execution time of a query (not the time to print out the result!!) with neo4j-shell? Using PROFILE?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello and welcome to the exiting world of Graph Databases.

The Neo4J browser console provides a print out of the execution time when you type in each cypher statement. 
As far as I am aware, this is the execution time and not the time taken to display the results using the visualization plugin.

If you are not satisfied with this and would like more accurate results / reliable results there are two options I can think of.

1. Use the Java API to create a Java Stored Procedure (Neo4J 3.0 and
   above) or a unmanaged extension to [extend the server](http://neo4j.com/docs/3.0.1/server-extending.html). This is
   [much](https://maxdemarzi.com/2012/11/26/extending-neo4j/) more [faster](https://maxdemarzi.com/2014/02/27/neo4j-at-ludicrous-speed/) as it is not restricted by the Cypher
   Query Planner (although this has improved significantly with 3.0)
2. Create a simple API server on the same VM / Machine as Neo4J and
   have it monitor the time it takes from the request to the DB to the
   Response and return it to you. I have something similar that logs api request times in my NodeJS Server so I can optimize queries. This is not a bad option given the new high performance [BOLT](http://neo4j.com/docs/3.0.1/bolt.html) interface. Although option 1 should still be faster.

Comment: Great! I will definitely try the first option. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help. Please mark as answered if this helped you out.

Comment: About the time shown in the neo4j browser, the documentation says: "don’t rely on that exact timing though it includes the latency and (de-)serialization costs, not just the actual query execution time." https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-neo4j-browser/

Answer (score 0):

Enterprise Edition of Neo4j allows you to enable logging of all the queries you've sent. See all config options starting with `dbms.logs.query.*` from http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/#config_dbms.logs.query.enabled.

Just amend to `conf/neo4j.conf`:

```
dbms.logs.query.enabled=true
```

Please note that for older (aka 2.x) versions of Neo4j the config options had a different naming convention.

Comment: Thanks Stefan. I'm using the Community Edition, but it's good to know if we decided to move to the Enterprise one.

Comment: @DanielaButano I'm trying to find the execution time of GDS algorithms using the community edition of Neo4j. Is there any way to find it rather than query logging? Since this facility is specific to the enterprise edition.